# WebClient asynchronous page request

Tags: c#, webclient

I've been trying to to get to read a page by WebClient api. But the page is too large so the response is too slow. Sometimes I need to wait for 2 and half minute to get the full response.

```
var client = new WebClient();
var stream = client.OpenRead("http://example.com");
using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // add line and do something else
    }
}
```

There must be a better way to deal with it. Can i asynchronously retrieve these data and on callback do my work?

Comment: If you look at the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144211.aspx there are OpenReadAsync method.  But if you could switch to HttpClient instead of WebClient you could use the Task based await and make your code a lot cleaner.

Comment: Are you looking for making code faster (unlikely unless server supports requests with "RANGE" headers for that type of pages) OR you are looking to do something else while code is waiting for download?

Comment: It has chunk of series of data. some parts of this data goes to db. Another parts process for UI. If the page could deliver results in small parts then we needed not to wait for full fetching.  @CharlesNRice can you share some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using HttpClient. The method this is in will need to return back a Task or Task<> and be marked as async.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    // This will process async
    var results = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://example.com");
    // This will process async
    var stream = await results.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = await sr.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
        {
            // add line and do something else
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't realized HttpClient only supported in 4.5. Its not an option for me since our project is in 4.0.

Comment: @nazmoonnoor, you can use `HttpClient` with .NET 4.0: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx

Comment: @CharlesNRice, I'd +1 this, if you did `line = await sr.ReadLineAsync()` instead of `line = sr.ReadLine()`, in row with the rest of the code. Otherwise, you're unnecessarily blocking the current thread.

Comment: @Noseratio Thanks I missed that.  OP wanted an HttpClient example from his comments but then said he couldn't because they don't use .Net 4.5 - so won't be much help to him.

Comment: @CharlesNRice, they still could use `async/await`, `HttpClient` and target .NET 4.0 with VS2012+ and [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async).

Comment: @Noseratio - Good to know.  I've been lucky and only have used 4.5